# how to render with jinja2 like twig render controller

Tags: include, jinja2, render

I'm now starting web development with python - Flask. I'd like to know if it's possible to do :
"Render with jinja like render controller with twig".

in my base.html file, I want to insert a code to manage notifications for logged-in users.